# std::pair<> behaves different on debug and release builds

Tags: android, c++, ios, xcode

I have a piece of code that returns an std::pair<> structure as below and it behaves differently on my debug and release builds

- std::pair<bool, const MyData&>: Works well in debug build, doesn’t work on release build (I get corrupted data)
- std::pair<bool, const MyData*>: Works well both in debug and release builds
- std::pair<bool, std::reference_wrapper>: reference_wrapper is created via std::cref,  works well both in debug and release builds
  I have a logic as below (it is the version with const MyData&):

```
std::pair<bool, const MyData&> MyClass::GetData() const
{
   // MyData has some complex data and data structure in it
   // MyData is held in std::map<MyData> myMap

   // Perform some searching operation in the map
   if(isFound)
   {
      return std::make_pair(true, myMap.at(...));
   }
   const static MyData emptyData; 
   return std::make_pair(false, emptyData);
}
```

Theoretically, I was expecting all cases more or less to work the same. I did some research on the internet and re-read my C++ references, but still could not find a real explanation for such behavior.
I compile my code with XCode 12.0 for iOS and Android projects.

Comment: Please privide a **minimal reproducible sample**. Apparently you are producing **UB**; Program happens to look working in debug mode, but crashes in release. To identify the source of UB, more info is needed.

Comment: Debug libraries often zero initialize memory (or write well know patterns) so everything is clean and easy to debug. While release builds don't add the extra code to zero things out (they assume you have written good code that correctly initializes everything). So this is probably the result of an uninitialized variable of member (have you compiled with all the warnings turned on? This may help you find uninitialized objects.

Comment: Does `MyData` have a default constructor? Otherwise `const static MyData emptyData;` may have different values between debug and release versions.

Comment: In providing a [mcve] you're going to - at the least - need to show how `myMap` is populated AND how the caller uses the returned pair.   Code that works differently between debug and release builds is a common symptom of undefined behaviour (pointer molestation, using a dangling pointer or reference, etc etc).    And the number of ways your code (or code you haven't shown and its interactions with code you have shown) can introduce undefined behaviour is approaching infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_pair` will make a copy. It will never return a pair with reference types.

Your `return std::make_pair(true, myMap.at(...));` will return a `std::pair<bool, MyData>` (copying the result of `myMap.at(...)`), which converts to a `std::pair<bool, const MyData&>`, where the returned value's `.second` is bound to the temporary that is immediately destroyed. This means your function returns a dangling reference.

Use `std::pair`'s constructor:

```cpp
// One of:
return { true, myMap.at(...) };
return std::pair<bool, const MyData&>(true, myMap.at(...));
```

(Also consider using just `const MyData*`, returning `nullptr` if it is not found. Barring that, `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const MyData>>` is also a good choice to replace pair with bool)